# Why does Jesus command his disciples not to move from house to house?

Tags: jesus, luke

Luke 10:7

> Stay in that house, eating and drinking what they give you; for the laborer is worthy of his wages. Do not keep moving from house to house. NASB

Why does Jesus command them not to move from house to house?

Comment: This is speculation, not an answer. Possibly each pair of disciples would visit many houses, eating only a little at each, feeling embarrassed to take so much from any one family. Jesus points out that they are doing a job, one that is worthy of its wages, and they should freely accept what is offered to them when it is offered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt this can be 'proved' from the text.

It is obvious that it would be socially disruptive, rude to the host, distracting to the preaching of the gospel and attention-drawing when the Lord himself should be in view.

One could list many, many scriptures about rudeness and selfish behaviour but surely nature is sufficient to teach us these things, quite apart from the scripture.

> Doth not even nature itself teach you, that, if a man have long hair, it is a shame unto him? [1 Corinthians 11:14 KJV]

It is one of those occasions when a matter is so obvious, that it does not need to be actually stated. Therefore it is not a matter of exegesis.

In a more extreme example Paul makes it clear that some forms of behaviour are abhorred by all nations, generally :

> It is reported commonly that there is ... among you, .. such .. as is not so much as named among the Gentiles [1 Corinthians 5:1 KJV],

proving that we do not, necessarily, need the bible to dissuade us from behaviour that is either unsociable or anti-social.

In this case, disciples may have thought it necessary to respond to multiple invitations but surely nature teaches that common sense should prevail.

Comment: I think this answer is as correct as it is ingenious.  Many thanks.